# How to efficiently get back a single value in ElasticSearch Aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider a example aggregation that I am doing to get a single value for each bucket, by using a scripted metric:

```
...
"aggs": {
  "students": {
    "terms": { 
      "field": "studentId"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "student_name": {
        "scripted_metric": {
          "map_script" : "_agg['value'] = doc['studentName'].value",
          "combine_script" : "return _agg['value']",
          "reduce_script" : "return _aggs[0]"
        }
      },
      ...
```

By doing this, I get results like this:

```
...
"students": {
  ...
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "Student302",
      "doc_count": 39,
      "student_name": {
        "value": "Mr. Student"
      },
      ...
```

In this case, I know that `studentName` is going to be the same for all docs bucketted by `studentId` so I know only need one results.

I would ideally like the results to be in the format shown in the example. I am aware of the tophits aggregator, which will do what I want when I set the hits to 1, but it would require additional post-processing to get the output format to be the same.

I am looking for a more efficient or ideal way to get back results in the same format, where there is a single "value" inside a "field_name".

Or: Is there any reason to not just use the scripted_metric as show above?

Note, I need to do this for several fields, and my concerns with using the scripted metric have to do with performance and maintenance.

Please advise if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply using another `terms` sub-aggregation on the `studentName` field, you'd get only one sub-bucket for certain.

Comment: I considered that too, but it's the same problem as the top-hits aggregator - that it will not produce the { "field_name": { "value" : "foo" } } result format

Comment: How is that a big deal?

Comment: I have a generic process that is flattening the output of the query and it is expecting it to be in that format. It is not a huge deal if I need to modify that process, but it might actually be easier to stick to the scripted_metrics approach which gives the output in the expected format. I just wanted to check if there is a better way to do that.